# Singleton service in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton

I have the following service:

```
export abstract class ILoggingService {
    // abstract functions here
}

export class LoggingService implements ILoggingService {
    // service implementation
}

export class MockLoggingService implements ILoggingService {
    // service implementation
}
```

Which I provide in the required modules using:

```
@NgModule()
export class SomeModule {
    providers: [
        { provide: ILoggingService, useClass: LoggingService }
    ]
}
```

Normal usage:

```
@Component({  
    selector: 'test-component',
    template: ''
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor(private readonly loggingService: ILoggingService) {
        // resolves to the correct instance (LoggingService), but not a singleton.
    }
}
```

I'm failing to create a singleton for this LoggingService. I have tried creating a LoggingServiceModule which uses the `forRoot()` strategy, which I couldn't get working.

I'm also not sure how to use the `provideIn: 'root'` implementation, as it needs to be provided using `{ provide: ILoggingService, useClass: LoggingService }`?

How can I combine the implementation where I map an interface (abstract class) to a concrete type, and the singleton pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root', useClass: LoggingService})
export abstract class ILoggingService {
 // abstract functions here
}
```

Thanks to this [article](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/aktuelles/the-new-treeshakable-providers-api-in-angular/)

Comment: Using this approach, another service injected into the LoggingService doesn't resolve. Ive @injected the other service the same way, but the instance of the service is undefined.

Comment: Interesting enough though, I've written a test application and its working in that one. So I will have to go back and see why this is happening. I think this is the correct solution though